# How to go from summarized data to raw data

Tags: r, function, multinomial

I first want to generate multinomially distributed data using r, and then I want the data in its "raw" form. So for an example, say that I have generated data by

```
 set.seed(1)
 df <- as.data.frame(cbind(rmultinom(1, 13, c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2)), seq(from = 0, to = 3, by = 1)))
```

I get

```
  V1 V2
  3  0
  2  1
  4  2
  4  3
```

I then want the data in a vector at the individual level, so that it looks like

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I´m new to this and it wasn´t as easy as I thought it would be. I tried to create a function that looked something like

```
xcv <- vector(length = m)


asdf <- function(x, n){
 for(i in 1:n){
   xcv[j] <-  seq(from = x[i,2], to = x[i,2], length.out = x[i,1])  

 }
return(xcv)
}
```

This did not work at all, so I hope to get some help.

Comment: are you talking about R programming language? please att the tag [tag:R] You'll get  higher change of getting an answer

Comment: Just use `rep`. (`rep(df$V2, df$V1)`, for instance). My "df" is different from yours, even though you seem to have used `set.seed`.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks!